# Set importance to mail when using Excel's envelope

Tags: vba, excel, envelope

I have created a macro, in Excel, to send mail.

I want to set the importance as high. I have tried

```
.Importance = 2
.olImportanceHigh = 2
.Importance = olImportanceHigh
```

It says Object does not support property or method.

```
ws1.Activate
    ToArray = wb1.Sheets("Report").Cells(3, 34).Value
    CCArray = wb1.Sheets("Report").Cells(3, 35).Value
    Subject = subject1
    Content = wb1.Sheets("Report").Cells(3, 36).Value
    ws1.Range("B3:P31").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With wb1.Sheets("New Report").MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = Content
    .Item.To = ToArray
    .Item.CC = CCArray
    .Item.Subject = Subject
    .Item.attachments.Add (wb2.FullName)
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh
    .Item.Send
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a property of the MailItem and not the MailEnvelope so you need to use:

```
.Item.Importance = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The "MailEnvelope" property of a worksheet returns an MsoEnvelope object. "Importance" is a property of the MailItem object so you need:

```
.Item.Importance = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ?

```
.Item.Importance = olImportanceHigh
```